# Visual Studio change default startup form when debugging

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Whenever i click start on a VS project, it opens with the default form set in properties.  How do i change it so that form i am working on is loaded instead of the properties startup form.  I am using VS2013 Ultimate.

Comment: You can't really. Think about the public/global variables that are needed for most forms and then ask yourself where they would come from if you did not get to it from your main form!

Comment: You can, i just forget how.

Its literally a property that i forget where its at.

Comment: I'm also not talking about when you launch the .exe, im talking about when you're created multiple forms in visual studio and click the start button to see how it looks...

Comment: Startup form in your project properties.

Comment: If i create 6 forms for a project, i do not want to go to properties every time.  Theres a property somewhere that lets you start from the form you're working in.  I just forget where its at.

Comment: I have never seen that except in Web Projects. Sorry I cannot help.

Comment: Appreciate the try.  Where is it for web projects?

Comment: As far as i know, there is no such property for start-up form, maybe you mean the similar property for **start-up project**, when you have more than 1 project in the same solution. This one is in the solution properties

Comment: ISAE - you're right, it was a multiple project solution i was working on.. Thank you for jogging my memory!

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Project Designer window by right-clicking My Project in the Solution Explorer window and then clicking Open on the context menu. Or, you can click Project on the menu bar and then click  Properties on the menu.

1.
Right-click My Project in the Solution Explorer window, and then click Open to open the Project Designer window.

2.
Auto-hide the Solution Explorer window.

3.
If necessary, click the Application tab to display the Application pane. If frmMain does not appear in the Startup form list box, click the Startup form list arrow and then click frmMain in the list.